# Tikz x labels as images creates asymmetrical spacing

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, axis

I sort of stumbled upon the idea of using pictures as x-axis labels for my graph in a thesis. However, I have run into the problem of the last label being further away (not symmetric) to the other labels, which I found weird. **Specifically, I am talking about the last observation for IBM.** I first made sure that the width of all pictures are somewhat similar, which they weren't originally. However, this did not fix the problem, so I am sort of lost right now. I am using the following code:

```
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pgfplot}

    \begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{AMD top 8 search based peers (2016)}
    \label{FigAMDtop10SBPpeers}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[width=15cm,height=8cm,
        ymin=0, ymax=8,
        xtick pos=lower,ytick pos=left,
        xtick style={draw=none},
        ylabel = Annual Search Fraction,
        yticklabel=\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=0,zerofill}\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%,
        axis background/.style={fill=gray!5},
        symbolic x coords={\includegraphics[scale=0.02]{Logo/intellogo.png},\includegraphics[scale=0.0175]{Logo/HPlogo.png},\includegraphics[scale=0.0175]{Logo/nvidialogo.png},\includegraphics[scale=0.0175]{Logo/broadcomlogo.png},\includegraphics[scale=0.0175]{Logo/texasinstrumentslogo.png},\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{Logo/googlelogo.png},\includegraphics[scale=0.02]{Logo/microsoftlogo.png}),\includegraphics[scale=0.007]{Logo/ibmlogo.png}
},
        xtick=data,
        nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\%},
        nodes near coords style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
        ]
        \addplot[ybar,fill={rgb:red,0;green,47;blue,135}] coordinates {
            (\includegraphics[scale=0.02]{Logo/intellogo.png},6.1529271206690564)
            (\includegraphics[scale=0.0175]{Logo/HPlogo.png},1.3888888888888888)
            (\includegraphics[scale=0.0175]{Logo/nvidialogo.png},1.045400238948626)
            (\includegraphics[scale=0.0175]{Logo/broadcomlogo.png},0.9557945041816009)
            (\includegraphics[scale=0.0175]{Logo/texasinstrumentslogo.png},0.9109916367980884)
            (\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{Logo/googlelogo.png},0.6869772998805257)
            (\includegraphics[scale=0.02]{Logo/microsoftlogo.png},0.6571087216248507)
            (\includegraphics[scale=0.007]{Logo/ibmlogo.png},0.6571087216248507),0.6421744324970132)

        };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
```

which then produces the following:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea as to why it is not symmetrical anymore, and how to fix it?

Comment: I also tried adjusting the size of Microsofts logo, but to no avail. I don't understand why you posit that the bars are equally spaces - they are clearly not?

Comment: You treat the symbolic coordinates differently: `symbolic x coords={\includegraphics[scale=0.02]{Logo/intellogo.png},\includegraphics[scale=0.0175]{Logo/HPlogo.png},\includegraphics[scale=0.0175]{Logo/nvidialogo.png},\includegraphics[scale=0.0175]{Logo/broadcomlogo.png},\includegraphics[scale=0.0175]{Logo/texasinstrumentslogo.png},\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{Logo/googlelogo.png},\includegraphics[scale=0.02]{Logo/microsoftlogo.png},0.6571087216248507),\includegraphics[scale=0.007]{Logo/ibmlogo.png},0.6571087216248507},`, there are two numeric ones at the end which explains it.

Comment: Hi Marmot, to understand you correct - are you talking about differing scaling? I also tried setting the scaling equal for all.

However, I also just spotted the mistake of two coordinates - I fixed that and edited the post, thank you!

EDIT: I also spotted the other mistake, like you mentioned. Formatting your code properly really does help you, thank you Marmot. :) This fixed it!

Comment: No, the next-to-next-to-last symbolic coordinate is `0.6571087216248507)` which however does not get used in the plot, and hence there is a gap.

Comment: Yes, thank you Marmot - see my edit. :)

Comment: The edit has the same problem, the last three symbolic x coordinates are `0.6571087216248507),\includegraphics[scale=0.007]{Logo/ibmlogo.png},0.6571087216248507`. Remove `0.6571087216248507),`. (This is an example of a question that is hard to answer with an explicit example since you include png files that most of us do not have.)

Comment: As marmot is saying, there is a typo in your input. the `0.6571087216248507`for microsoft  is accidentally repeated. The end of the `\addplot` statement should be `(\includegraphics[scale=0.02]{Logo/microsoftlogo.png},0.6571087216248507)
            (\includegraphics[scale=0.007]{Logo/ibmlogo.png},0.6421744324970132)};`.